# With apt info, how do I see additional records, if -a doesn't work?

Tags: apt, package-management

When I run (for example) `apt info python3.8`, the last line of the output is the following one.

> N: There is 1 additional record. Please use the '-a' switch to see it

Following what that line suggested, I tried `apt info -a python3.8`, but all I got is the following error message.

> E: Command line option 'a' [from -a] is not understood in combination with the other options.

Thinking it simply meant the option should be the first one, I tried `apt -a info python3.8` and `apt -a python3.8` but I got the exact same error message.

To my surprise, even `apt -a` gave me the same error message.

How can I see the additional records, if the suggested option doesn't work?

Notice that this happens with a fresh installation of Pop!_OS 19.10, on a virtual machine and on a physical machine. I take it cannot be caused from conflicts between installed packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description, it sounds like your issue is related to this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1843812)

The report has an easy workaround while awaiting for the `apt-1.9.5` package to be released to your distribution:

```
apt show -a $pkg
```

Comment: I would have never thought `info` was an alias of `show`. To say the truth, neither `man apt` nor `man apt-cache` say `info` is accepted as sub-command.